# Separate attribute from element in beamer-slides

Tags: listings

Using custom listings to markup my XML in beamer slides, I want to separate the `attribute` from the `element`, making `attribute` green rather than blue. I also want to make the black signs light gray. How do I accomplish this? I'm not using minted, but listings.

[image]

Edit: Here is my code for reproduction:

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\definecolor{dkgreen}{RGB}{151,205,160}
\definecolor{test}{RGB}{255,212,212}
\definecolor{mauve}{RGB}{255,187,185}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{176,223,224}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{light-gray}{RGB}{77,77,77}
\definecolor{numbers}{RGB}{255,153,29}
\definecolor{whitewhite}{RGB}{214,214,214}


\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{numbers},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},      % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  frame=none,                   % adds a frame around the code
  rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  title=\lstname,                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
                              % also try caption instead of title  
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape
}


\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[s][\color{mauve}]{"}{"},
  morestring=[s][\color{whitewhite}]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  morecomment=[s][\color{dkgreen}]{<!--}{-->},
  stringstyle=\color{orange},
  identifierstyle=\color{lightblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{test},
  morekeywords=       {xmlns,xsi,noNamespaceSchemaLocation,type,id,x,y,source,target,version,tool,transRef,roleRef,objective,eventually,skos}% list your attributes here
}
\begin{document}

   \begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=xml]
<element attribute="#attributevalue" />
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you can use `\lstset{}` as described in `listings` documentation, section 1.3 and further

Answer (score 1):

- Colouring `attribute` in a different colour can be achieved by creating, for example, a new keywordstyle for it (keyword is just an example, as I don't know enough about XML to judge which category would be fitting).
- to change the colour of the normal text (`=` etc.) you can change the basic style
- Off-topic: you don't need `color` when you load `xcolor` and in fact you don't need to load neither of both with `beamer`

---

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{xcolor} 

\definecolor{dkgreen}{RGB}{151,205,160}
\definecolor{test}{RGB}{255,212,212}
\definecolor{mauve}{RGB}{255,187,185}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{176,223,224}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{light-gray}{RGB}{77,77,77}
\definecolor{numbers}{RGB}{255,153,29}
\definecolor{whitewhite}{RGB}{214,214,214}


\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{white},
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{numbers},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},      % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  frame=none,                   % adds a frame around the code
  rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  title=\lstname,                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
                              % also try caption instead of title  
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape
}


\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[s][\color{mauve}]{"}{"},
  morestring=[s][\color{whitewhite}]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  morecomment=[s][\color{dkgreen}]{<!--}{-->},
  stringstyle=\color{orange},
  identifierstyle=\color{lightblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{test},
  morekeywords=       {xmlns,xsi,noNamespaceSchemaLocation,type,id,x,y,source,target,version,tool,transRef,roleRef,objective,eventually,skos},% list your attributes here
  morekeywords=[2]{attribute},
  keywordstyle=[2]\color{green}
}
\begin{document}

   \begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=xml]
<element attribute="#attributevalue" />
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see. You add another type of keyword style with distinct keywords and apply a color value to them. Many thanks!

Comment: @phronesismimesis That is the basic approach. I just don't know if keyword is the correct category because I don't know much about XML.

Comment: Well, one issue that I found was that when I specified the attribute "RDF" as green, the element "RDF" in a root tag went green as well, while I would like that to be blue. Not sure if there's a way around this. Basically I'd like to specify the colorscheme as per https://github.com/junegunn/seoul256.vim.

Comment: @phronesismimesis I am sorry, I have no idea what a root tag might be.

Comment: @phronesismimesis You're welcome!